# Failed to resolve: firebase-storage-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle, firebase-storage

When I add Firebase to my application it shows this error:

> Failed to resolve: 'firebase-storage-15.0.0'

And an error on this line: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rud.younis.csedepertment"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can I see your project level `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some major typos in your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

What's with the `16.0.1:15.0.0` ?

Change it to `15.0.0` or `16.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> Failed to resolve: 'firebase-storage-15.0.0'

Because you are using a wrong dependencies in your code. To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
```

Because versions such as `16.0.1:15.0.0` does not exist.

In your top level `build.gradle` file please be sure to have the latest version of Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Hi Younis! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just updated my android studio and it fixes the error. So, just update your android studio.